# Can't get chrome extension to get innerText when loading

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I am building my first chrome extension and want to read the entire text in the website whenever a new tab is loaded. Everything works with a button, but I can't trigger it automatically.

Here's what I have in my `popup.js`

```
let getWords = document.getElementById("getWords");


// When the button is clicked, inject getPageText into current page
getWords.addEventListener("click", async () => {
    let [tab] = await chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, currentWindow: true });
  
    chrome.scripting.executeScript({
      target: { tabId: tab.id },
      func: getPageText,
    });
    
});

chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tab) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript({
        target: { tabId: tab.id },
        func: getPageText,
    }); 
});
  
// The body of this function will be executed as a content script inside the
// current page
function getPageText() {
    let websiteWords = document.body.innerText;
    console.log(websiteWords);
}
```

My `popup.html`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/layout.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/ui.css" />
  </head>

  <body>
    BODY
  </body>
    <button id="getWords">Words</button>

  <script src="popup.js"></script>
</html>
```

on my `background.js` I tried this but it doesn't work:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab){
  if(changeInfo.status === "complete"){
    console.log("loaded....")
  }
});


function getPageText() {
  let websiteWords = document.body.innerText;
  console.log(websiteWords);
}
```

Finally my `manifest.json`

```
"manifest_version": 3,
"permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "webNavigation",
        "storage",
        "scripting"
    ],
    "host_permissions": [
      "https://*/*"
    ],
    "background": {
        "service_worker": "background.js",
        "type": "module"
    },
    "action": {
        "default_popup": "popup.html"
    },
```

Comment: The popup (and its onUpdated listener) runs only when the popup is shown. You don't need a background script for this. Instead you can declare a content script in manifest.json which will run it automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use content_scripts.

manifest.json

```
{
  "name": "hoge",
  "version": "1.0",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "<all_urls>"
      ],
      "js": [
        "matches.js"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

matches.js

```
function getPageText() {
  let websiteWords = document.body.innerText;
  console.log(websiteWords);
}

getPageText();
```